# React-native array stack of imageviews - how to animate only topmost item?

Tags: react-native

essentially, I want to build something like the tinder swipe left/right functionality.

I have a stack of 10 Imageviews within an array. On button click, I would like to have the topmost imageview with index 9 animated to the left and pushed back in the array using splice to index 0.

I am not sure what the best approach for such a behaviour is in react-native. What I did so far:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        images: [],
    };
}
```

Then I fetch the imageviews async and add them to the state with a prop of shouldAnimate=false:

```
json.images.map((e,key) => {
    img.push(<Images key={e.id} shouldAnimate={false} uri={e.src} />);
  });
```

Then in my button click function I try changing the prop shouldanimate to true such that the imageview animates itself.

**EDIT:**

[image: This is the array of components in the state]

```
let newArr = this.state.images.map((elem, idx) => {);
  if(idx === 9) {
    //update should animate
    elem.props.shouldAnimate = true;
  }
  return elem;
})
console.log(newArr);
```

Using the debugger, however, I can see that the shouldAnimate is actually never set to true.

I think I am being really thick here... sorry. Also, I am really not sure whether it is a good idea to store the imageviews in store.

Any help is much appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is how the `map` function works.
The `map` will never change the actual array, you need to assign it to a new array:

```
     let newArray = imgArr.map((elem, idx) => {
      if(idx === 9) {
        //update should animate
        elem.props.shouldAnimate = true;
      }
      return images;
    })
    console.log(newArray)
```

the new array will have a props with true value.

Comment: Thx, I edited the code, but unfortunately the returned array from console log, still has shouldAnimate false for the element at index 9.

Comment: Can you pls provide the array content too ?

Comment: pls check this sandbox, the 9th element has true value for `shouldAnimate`.
https://codesandbox.io/s/pwo38zqy80

Comment: Thanks oma for the sandbox. I see that it is working fine with a normal array. What I am doing differently though is that I am pushing a component to the array: <Images key={e.id} shouldAnimate={false} uri={e.src} />. And that array lies in store.
It seems that simply doing a map over the array containing the components and trying to change the prop of the component directly is not possible... There is probably a much better way of doing this which I don't know atm.

Comment: But you array is not "normal" ? :D can you send us your array ?

Comment: Oh, I see. Maybe you should take a look here:  https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/direct-manipulation

Comment: yea I am really unsure whether it is a good idea to store the components within an array inside the store. I added the contents of the array in my OP.

Comment: I see, will test it today, this afternoon. If I found something useful for you will be back.

Comment: Thanks a lot Oma!!! With your help, I managed to solve it after a lot of struggle. I guess it is not difficult in the end, but one needs to think in terms of state and props when it comes to react.

Answer (score 0):

@Oma - thanks for your help man! I was able to solve it - the link was very helpful :)

Quickoverview of what I do:

I get the image information from an async fetch and store that

```
json.images.map((e,id) => {
  img.push({
    key: id,
    shouldAnimate: this.state.shouldAnimArr[id].shouldAnimate,
    uri: e.src
  })
});
this.setState({
  imageViews: img,
  isLoading: false
})
```

When I click the like image button I copy the state array, change the shouldAnimate to true on one element and set the state with the new array.

```
likeImage() {
  let imgArrShouldAnimate = this.state.shouldAnimArr.slice();
  let newArr2 = imgArrShouldAnimate.map((elem, idx) => {
    if(idx === 9) {
      elem.shouldAnimate = true;
    }
    return elem;
  })
  this.setState({
    imgArrShouldAnimate: newArr2
  });
}
```

I render the images using this:

```
{this.state.imageViews.map(e => {
  return (
    <Images key={e.key} shouldAnimate={this.state.shouldAnimArr[e.key].shouldAnimate} uri={e.uri} />
  )
})}
```